# TypeScript - Return type of function that returns new instance

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a TypeScript function returning a **new instance of Elasticsearch**:

```
public getClient(): any {
    return new Elasticsearch.Client({
        host: ['url', ':', 'port'].join(''),
        plugins: [ESDeleteByQuery],
        log: 'logType'
    });
}
```

I want to change the **any** function return type to something more specific. I tried, just out of curiosity, to change the return type from **any** to **string**, **boolean** or **{}** and it successfully passes the compilation event though it does not match the returned value of **new Elasticsearch.Client(...)**. What should be the correct function return type?

Comment: `Elasticsearch.Client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, don't bother... typescript will infer the return type from what you return:

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I would expect TypeScript to generate error if set the return type of the function to, for example, **void** (as I stated in my code atop this page). It passes the compilation instead, which is weird if I return **new Elasticsearch.Client(...)**.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you; http://imgur.com/8hImGXQ set it to `void` or `boolean` and it will fail. Set it to `{}` and it will pass because its will allow any object through... `Elasticsearch.Client` is the answer to the question you asked. :)